# Setting .mask()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mask

How can I configure `.mask()` method to get values between 99.99 and 999.999.999.999,9999 ?

I'm trying:

```
$("input").mask("###.###.###.#99,9999");
```

and

```
$('input').mask('###.###.###.#99,9999', {translation: {'Z': {pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true}}});
```

But I do not succeed.

I'm using jquery.mask(). What should I do?

Comment: How exactly do you not succeed? Does the code throw an error? Does the input get masked not as expected? Does it get not masked at all?

Comment: The mask does not work, it appears in the field ###.###.###.#__,____, I can not change the values "#"

Comment: In the mask you are using dots and in your example you are using commas. Maybe that is the reason, I have never used mask.

Comment: what mask plugin are you using?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to comment. I'm using jquery.mask().

Comment: @Joerg, it is not a number, the "thousand" and "decimal" letters are arbitrary - so there is no difference in using `,` or `.` ...